# Is there a way to disable my profile picture on outlook 2010?

Tags: outlook

I want to disable my profile picture on outlook 2010 professional plus. Is there a way to do so? The server is controlled by our company.

Comment: Does the picture come from your Exchange server, Facebook, or LinkedIn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the picture comes from Exchange, your only option to ask your Exchange admin to remove it from the AD.

Comment: What is AD? Administrative Directory?

Comment: Active Directory. Is this a programming question?

Comment: Not really. I mean I was just looking to disable the picture.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that.